# How to turn a folder with 3 Python scripts and 1 UI into an executable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, exe

So right now, I have 3 scripts, 1 is a class that I used, 1 is a list of functions, 1 is UI.

UI is the "main" script, it also uses a .ui file made with QtDesigner. But I don't know how to turn this into an executable, using PyCharm or anything? I searched for pyinstaller and py2exe but can't figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

[PyInstaller](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search)

you can import your other files in different folders using **import** :

## Import directory-name/python-filename-without-extension

## Example:-

`#!/usr/bin/python3 
import additional-files/filename`